# BigDecimal in ObjectNode getting rounded when storing in database

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, rounding, bigdecimal

I am storing ObjectNode and the objectNode is the object of a class which contains a BigDecimal attribute, when we store a big number in the ObjectNode and store that ObjectNode in the postgress, the big quantity is getting rounded off

ANy solution

I tried to

`@JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON) @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb") @JsonProperty("properties") private ObjectNode transaction;`

on the entity but this is changing the ObjectNode as string, but I dont want that